# Why IFormFile is null in nested object?

Tags: c#, forms, file, asp.net-core, multipartform-data

I've got these models

```
public sealed class UpdateFacilityReportFirstStepCommand : ICommand<ExecutionResult>
{
    // other props

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the hired staff.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The hired staff.</value>
    public List<HiredStaffUpsertModel> HiredStaff { get; set; } = new List<HiredStaffUpsertModel>();
}

public class HiredStaffUpsertModel
{
    // other props

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the insurance card file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The insurance card file.</value>
    public HiredStaffCarInsuranceCardModel CarInsuranceCardFile { get; set; } = new HiredStaffCarInsuranceCardModel();
}

public class HiredStaffCarInsuranceCardModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The file.</value>
        [FileValidator("pdf,doc,docx", 10 * 1024 * 1024, true)]
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value><c>true</c> if this instance is changed; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
        public bool IsChanged { get; set; }
    }
```

And in my controller I'm expecting public `[FromForm] UpdateFacilityReportFirstStepCommand command`.
That's how I send form in Postman (content-type: multipart/form-data):
[image]

And that's what I get:
[image]

I have no idea why my `File` is null, although bool `IsChanged` is received. My frontend developer said that he'll send me form keys like on the Postman screenshot, and I don't get why it works fine with primitive types and doesn't with files.

Comment: I've just noticed, that if I send file with such key HiredStaff[0].CarInsuranceCardFile.File, it's not null. But I need to use square brackets. And another interesting thing is that bool can be sent HiredStaff[0].CarInsuranceCardFile.IsChanged or HiredStaff[0][CarInsuranceCardFile][IsChanged], while File can only be sent with dots.

Comment: We decided to send form keys with dot separator, still I don't understand why it doesn't work with square brackets.

Comment: I test with string type,bool type,custom model type,and can use square brackets,maybe it is by design.And in postman,no matter what type it is,we usually use xx.xxx.xxx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I found to solve it, it's same as yours.

```
public class Purchase 
{
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public IFormFile ProductImage { get; set; }
}
```

You have to send it like `Products[0].ProductImage`, otherwise you'll get `null` in `ProductImage`.